# How do I use the Vim code for Google's python style?

Tags: python

I found interesting code on GitHub at https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/google_python_style.vim

I would like to use it, but when I just dropped it in my .vimrc, it interfered with editing of other kinds of code such as C. How do I associate it with Python code only?

Answer (score 1):

That file is an "indent script", its content has nothing to do in your `vimrc`.

You are supposed to save it as:

- `~/.vim/after/indent/python.vim` (Unix-like systems)
- `%userprofile%\vimfiles\after\indent\python.vim` (Windows)

Concretely, Vim already comes with an indent script for Python and the indent script you are trying to install depends on it. By saving it under `after/`, you ensure that it is sourced, automatically, *after* the built-in one.

Comment: If that's the case, are things in .vim/after sourced automatically somehow, or do I have to invoke it?

Comment: Hmm.  Now that I'm paying more attention, I fail to see anything in this code that would make it specific to Python sources.  Maybe I should just ignore it.

Comment: [This line](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/google_python_style.vim#L45) makes the script very much Python-specific.

Comment: @ForDummies RE: `.vim/after`, it should be on your runtimepath. See `:help runtimepath` for all the things that can be in it which are invoked automatically or by special commands like `:compiler`